# Word Break at a particular text for different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I need to show the heading such that whenever we reduce the screen size it should show more than single word at second line.

Example:

> **Actual fit with browser**
>
> Word Break at a perticular text for different screen resolutions
>
> **It should represent like**
>
> Word Break at a perticular text for different
>
> screen resolutions
>
> **Not like this one**
>
> Word Break at a perticular text for different screen
>
> resolutions

I tried using `<wbr>` and `&shy;` but not able to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might insert a `&nbsp;` between the words *screen* and *resolution*. Or you can wrap the two words in `span` element with a `white-space: nowrap;` applied:

---

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meqvGw

```
<p>Word Break at a perticular text for different 
   screen&nbsp;resolutions</p>

<p>Word Break at a perticular text for different 
   <span style="white-space: nowrap;">screen resolutions</span><p>
```

Anyway I would go with the latter example, since you can can remove that property via mediaqueries on smaller viewports

Comment: We can't know how much space it is occupying right. So how many &nbsp; can be added to it we didn't know

Comment: you asked to have more than one single word on the last line. So a single non breaking space is enough

Comment: Solved in an easy manner. Spent so many hours on it by media queries